# How do I create a column that is fluid up to a certain point?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a two-column layout where the right column is fixed, and the left column is flexible up to a certain maximum width depending on the parent's width. For example, in the diagram below, I want the right column fixed at 100px and the left column to fill the parent's empty space up to 100px, at which point it stops expanding.

[image: Diagram of what I'm hoping to achieve]

For the first three examples, I can use a table with `table-layout: fixed`, but this doesn't work for the last example because I can't seem to set a `max-width` on the first column.

Ideally, this would be CSS-only (no JavaScript) and without using media queries (since it's based on the parent and not the viewport).

If it's relevant, the first column will itself be or contain a table.

Edit:

Here is some code that I have tried that has not worked: http://jsfiddle.net/cdp46fnx/1/

Comment: Please include all relevant code to your question, always.  What you have tried would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood what you're trying to accomplish, but here's one of the possible solutions (not sure if it will fit your needs):http://jsfiddle.net/Arministrator/0uuxvqkt/

I assumed you'll have some external element that affects your main elements:

```
<div id="site_width">
<div id="main">
  <div id="c2">2</div>
  <div id="c1">1</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And then adjust CSS so that your container has both min and max width. Float one of the columns right, and let other fill the remaining space. When there's minimum width of 150px right column will be 100 and left 50. If width is over 200, both columns will be 200 and the rest of the space is empty (external element.)
You can change this site_width ID to check all solutions